# Custom markers not showing on some devices (Google Maps Android SDK)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have Google Maps SDK running with custom markers on an android app. Everything works fine on our test phones -- an S3, an S5 and a DROID. However, when I run the app on Nexus 5 hardware, one type of custom marker stops showing up on the map.

While the markers are not showing up, they are *still* being drawn on the map. We can tap where the marker is supposed to be and it will perform desired behavior.

We're super confused about this, especially because another custom marker (that is very similar) works fine. Other than hardware, the only other difference between our test phones and the Nexus 5 is that the Nexus is running Android 6.0, vs 5.x and 4.x for our test phones.

Any insight would be super appreciated!

Edit: Here is the code where we draw the markers:

Where mMap is a Google Map:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(position)
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(annotationIcon)))
```

[image]

same issue i am facing in google map,some marker icons are displaying white on nexus and lg2 but working properly.

Comment: Show the code that you're using that draws the custom markers

Comment: Hi @DanielNugent, I added the code as an edit above. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show how you define annotationIcon?

Comment: @coder-don did you manage to solve the issue ? because I am facing the same problem ?

Comment: Nope. Never figured it out -- we found marker graphics that worked through trial and error and stuck with those. Really hoping that someone else has figured out a solution.