# Custom marker is not drawn on some devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, motorola-droid

I wanted to draw a marker on Google map based on some location data I collected. When I tested the code using Galaxy S5 it draws the marker but when I try to do the same thing using a Motorola it fails to draw the marker at times and draws it other times. The object the marker represents is always there even in the Motorola. The Galaxy runs Android 5.1.1 and the Motorola 5.1: the code is as follows.

```
private MarkerOptions getMarkerForItem(Provider pro, LatLng lctionll, float brng){
        MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
        isMarkerAlive = true;
       mo.icon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cuteMarker)))
               .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f) //so marker rotates around the center
               .position(lctionll)
               .rotation(brng)
               .flat(true);
        return mo;
    }
```

There is similar [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820868/custom-markers-not-showing-on-some-devices-google-maps-android-sdk) but there is no answer regarding the hardware differences and how to deal with these issues. Can someone help?

EDIT---> The Galaxy has Google play services 9.2.56 and the Motorola has 9.4.52

Comment: what is there in "cuteMarker" drawable? how big is that drawable in terms of pixels?

Comment: It is a custom drawable that is 18 X 32 and bigger per the android image size requirement. As far as the size go, I found it to be the correct size I wanted on all screen sizes including the Motorola phone. As stated in the question it works sometimes and other times the object is there but it is not drawn on the map.

Comment: Did you receive kind of errors?

Comment: Not errors but the value of the marker is null when I debug it. Strangely enough though, this occurs only with the Motorola phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding .visible(true) fixed it in the Motorola phone. I will test other devices and update this answer as needed.

```
MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().icon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.movingcab)))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f) //so marker rotates around the center
                .position(lctionll)
                .rotation(brng)
                .visible(true)
                .flat(true);
```